# First time FastAPI with 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: python, debugging, fastapi, http-status-code-500

I just start to learn FastAPI and follow the code from: [Full stack Fastapi Postgresql](https://github.com/tiangolo/full-stack-fastapi-postgresql)
to build my own backend api services.
In my DB, I have only one table that created by:
`CREATE TABLE public.users ( id text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL, user_name character varying(100) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL, full_name character varying(100) COLLATE pg_catalog."default", password text COLLATE pg_catalog."default", CONSTRAINT users_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id) )`

Everything looks fine, I could start the service by when I access /api/v1/user, I get the 500 error. Could anyone help me to show where could I change to make this code run (My code is here: https://github.com/dzungld/fastpro). And please give me some comment for the question: **How to debug Python on VScode**.

Comment: You should have an actual error present in the error log for your python process. Error 500 can be anything; it just tells you that something went wrong.

Comment: Look in the terminal/console where you ran your FastAPI app. It should have an error log (starts with "Traceback") with (hopefully) more details about which Exceptions were raised and from which part of your code. You should [edit] that error into this post, along with a [mcve] of the code that produced it (no, a Github link is not OK).